# How to restore frame to frameless Electron window

Tags: electron

Using ElectronJS, how do you change an existing frameless window into a framed window?

Something like this:

```
const splashWindow = createWindow('splash', {
  width: 500,
  height: 300,
  frame: false,
});

splashWindow.addFrame();
// Now splashWindow has a frame
```

Comment: `createWindow` isn't on the doc nor `addFrame` what are you using?

Comment: `createWindow()` is a custom function (I put that there for brevity)  `addFrame()` is the hypothetical function that adds a frame to a frameless window, i.e. what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can only set `frame` when creating a `BrowserWindow`